# Подсчет записей из разных таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Вопрос больше об оптимизации запроса. Дело в том, что пользователь может добавлять разного типа публикации (новости, статьи, заметки, фото).
Все это хранится по разным таблицам.

Каков будет оптимальный запрос на подсчет публикаций каждого типа?

`UNION ALL` не подходит, так как в таблицах разное число колонок.

Сделал так, не знаю, насколько быстрый вариант:

```
SELECT (

SELECT IF(`Count` IS NULL, 0, `Count`)
FROM likes
WHERE IdNote = 600
) AS likes, (

SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM commenttousers
WHERE CommentToUsersIdToUser =600
) AS reviews
FROM likes, commenttousers
GROUP BY CommentToUsersIdToUser
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

В моем примере почему-то не работает условие `IF`.

Comment: @Vasile, как вариант хранить эти данные в кэше (любой key-value storage) и инкрементить после каждого добавления в БД.

Comment: @Vasile, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ответе на запрос о количестве строк нужного типа будет одинаковое количество колонок, его и суммируй через union

```
select sum(A.B) from (select count(*) as B from tab1 union all select count(*) as B from tab2) as A;
```